# What does the monogram MCF stand for?

Tags: the-godfather-2

In [The Godfather II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather_Part_II), before gunmen try and kill him, when Michael enters his bedroom and Kay wakes up, we can see that bed linen has a monogram "**mCf**" on it.

[image: bed linen showing MCF monogram]

My search shows that it could be standing for:

1. Michael Corleone Francis (for the middle name).
2. Michael Corleone Family.

But I can't find any source providing reliable and undeniable evidence for a definitive answer.

**What does the MCF monogram stand for?**

Comment: It's the first one. Monograms such as these will emphasise the family name as the large letter. I'd have to check to see if Michaels middle name is ever stated as being Francis.

Comment: Connie and Carlo son is named Michael Francis Rizzi (his Godfather's names?) IIRC

Answer (score 16):

This is how monograms work.  The center initial is the surname, and the first initial is the first name, and the last initial is the middle name.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogram, see Individual Monograms:

> A basic 3-letter monogram has the initial of the individual's last name (surname) set larger, or with some special treatment in the center, while the first name initial appears to the left of it and the middle name initial appears to the right of it. There is a difference in how this is written for men and women. For example, if the individual's name is Mary Ann Jones, and Jones is the surname, then the arrangement of letters would be thus: MJA, with the surname initial set larger in the center, the M for Mary to the left and the A for Ann to the right.

Comment: So his middle name is Francis? I couldn't find any confirmation.

Comment: You provided an explanation on monograms, but no confirmation that Michael Corleone's middle name is Francis...

Comment: @steelersquirrel : neither could I, except for his godson "Michael Francis Rizzi" (godfather gives his names to godson?) but I can't find reliable source to back this up (and that would make the answer!).

Comment: @OldPadawan Agreed.  This answer does not answer your question.  Unfortunately, it will continue to get needless upvotes as it made it to HNQ ;)

Comment: Well, it's giving an opinion, which is allowed and fine though but I'd rather get what I couldn't find :)

Comment: @OldPadawan Yes, it's allowed; however, it doesn't make it a good answer.  If OP would add source and explanation to the answer explaining what the monogram stands for, then it would be a good answer :)

Comment: Since this is how monograms work, we can conclude that his middle name begins with F. It doesn't have to be specifically Francis.

Comment: According to this article, it is Francis. But the article simply state's it as fact, it doesn't give any justification for stating it.
https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1990-12-23-ca-9701-story.html

Comment: Did *Francis* Ford Coppola just insert his own name in there as an Easter Egg or something?

Comment: Could be Michael _F—IN_ Corleone

Comment: This answer does not rely on any particular middle name being correct, and does not need to address it. The querent was confused due to a misunderstanding on how monograms work; this answer addresses it.

Comment: @OrangeDog Of course Michael's middle name is Francis. It's in the dialog and everything, remember the baptism scene?

Comment: @Sneftel odd that it's not in the page for the character in any wiki I looked at.

Comment: It's in the script. And the film, of course.

Comment: @Sneftel  In the baptism scene, he christens Connie's baby, Michael's Godson as Michael Francis Rizzi.  The baptism scene says nothing about Michael Corleone's middle name